# Cannot find GenAi on "My Communities" drop down

Tags: support, status-bydesign

This site does not show up on the "My Communities" drop down menu

[image]

Is this a bug or is this just how it is for now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Private betas are generally not shown in public.**

This includes the site switcher, [all sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#newest), user profile (though network profile shows it), [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com), etc.

However, users can edit and add this site to their own "Your Communities" list.

See also: [Is there a reason that CS50 and edx-cs169-1x are not present in SEDE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251536/241919)

Answer (score 1):

Because this community is following a special process, asking about missing features is fine. You might want to keep an eye on [GenAI (previously Prompt Design) site stakeholder group updates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391232/1359324).

As mentioned by Andrew you might add GenAI Stack Exchange to "Your communities".

1. Click on the Stack Exchange button at the right of the toolbar
2. Click on edit
   [image: YOUR COMMUNITIES - edit]

   [image: Add community dialog]
3. Type GenAI
   [image: Add community dialog with suggestions]
4. Click Add

---

While this site hasn't an Area 51 proposal, this site is in the "limited private beta" stage of the Area 51 new site proposal process. Because it's in this stage, some features aren't available yet, like having the GenAI listed in the site selector, https://stackexchange.com/sites, https://data.stackexchange.com/, among others.

Besides not having an Area 51 proposal, there are some remarkable differences

1. Instead of "proposal committers", there is a Stakeholders group. The Stakeholders group has explicit writing access to the Prompt Design Stakeholders chatroom hosted at https://meta.stackexchange.com and to Stack Overflow for Teams instance.
2. Anyone could join the "limited private beta" https://genai.stackexchange.com since last week.
3. July 26th, is the official launch. It's very likely that there will be an official announcement.